# Using the OR Operator Function in Text Email Templates

Tags: email, formula, email-template, merge-field

I have a text email template and I'd like to display a paragraph of text if `Destination__c` is either `Barcelona` *OR* `Buenos Aires`.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
{!IF(OR(Enquiry__c.Destination__c = "Barcelona", Enquiry__c.Destination__c = "Buenos Aires"), "Yes", "No")}
```

I don't want to create a formula field just to display a paragraph of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if that works for you

```
{!IF(Enquiry__c.Destination__c = "Barcelona" || Enquiry__c.Destination__c = "Buenos Aires"), "Yes", "No")}
```

Otherwise, formula will be option which I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Doesn't work in an email template, but after I created a custom formula field, it worked!  Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: I told you at my earlier answer that formula works great